# How to properly render a PayPal button with other elements using PHP array?

Tags: php, paypal

I've got four products which are inserted with PHP from a MySql table. All four div containers are rendered fine, with the product name, price etc, apart from the PayPal button which appears only in the first div container for the first product.

I've tried to put the PayPal code in various places and all I have achieved was to render four PayPal buttons stuck on top of each other, again, only in the first div container with the first product.

I can't figure out how to make the PayPal button visible in each of the four div containers.

I've also tried to echo the button from MySQL table.

My code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=GBP"></script>
</head>


<body>
<?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cards ORDER BY id ASC";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
        ?>
    <form method="post" action="shopping-cart.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <div class="shop-pic-container">
            <div class="container">
                <span class="pic-side"> (Back) </span>
                <div class="vertical-line">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row['img_back_url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['img_back_alt']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <span class="pic-side"> (Front) </span>
                <div class="vertical-line">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row['img_front_url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['img_front_alt']; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="description-wrapper">
                <ul class="list-container">
                    <li class="card-description-title"><?php echo $row['product']; ?></li>
                    <li class="card-description">Size: A6</li>
                    <li class="no-style-li"><span class="card-dimensions">105 x 148 mm (4&frac18; × 5&frac78; in)</span></li>
                    <li class="card-description">Printed on 300gsm paper</li>
                    <li class="card-description">Blank on the inside</li><br>
                    <li class="card-description-price">Price: £ <?php echo $row['price']; ?>
                        <span class="free-postage">Free UK delivery</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <span class="no-style-li quantity-text">Quantity :</span>
                <span class="no-style-li"><input class="quantity" type="number" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" max="50"></span>
                <span><input type="hidden" name="hidden_photo" value="<?php echo $row['img_front_url']; ?>"></span>
                <span><input type="hidden" name="hidden_photo_alt" value="<?php echo $row['img_front_alt']; ?>"></span>
                <span><input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row['product']; ?>"></span>
                <span><input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"></span>
                <span><input type="hidden" name="hidden_quantity" value="<?php echo $row['quantity']; ?>"></span>
                <input class="add-to-cart" type="submit" name="add" value="Add to cart">
                <div id="paypal-button-container" class="paypal-buy-it-now"></div> <!-- ====== PAYPAL BUTTON ====== -->
            </div>
        </div> 
    </form>
    <?php
        }
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
   
    <script>
            paypal.Buttons({
                style: {
                    color: "silver",
                    label: "buynow",
                    layout: "horizontal",
                    local: "en_UK",
                    shape: "rect",
                    size: "responsive",
                    tagline: "false"
                }
            }).render("#paypal-button-container")</script>
</body>
```

I thought that putting the paypal.Buttons() script in the empty div with the id="paypal-button-container" would solve the problem but that was when I got four buttons stuck on top of each other in the first  As I understand, the script was basically executed four times and rendered the buttons immediately. I have tired sciript defer but it didn't make any difference either.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNa2t.png)

Comment: Possible solution could be to echo the PayPal div: `<?php echo "<div id='paypal-button-container' class='paypal-buy-it-now'></div>; ?>`